# check if data already exist in database and refuse

Tags: php, sql

hi I need to insert a parameter that allows when a user tries to enter a nick "$add_nick" check if this is already in the database, and if it is already present in the database needs to show a message saying "this nick Already exist"

can someone help me?
thanks

this is the code:

```
<?
if($go==="add" && $add_name && $add_serial && $add_nick && isset($_SESSION['captcha_spam']) && $_POST["captchacode"] == $_SESSION['captcha_spam'])
{
add_queue($add_name, $add_serial, $add_nick);
unset($_SESSION['captcha_spam']);

?>

<?php
exit;
}
elseif($go === "add")
{
$error = "U forgot to fill out something!";
}

if($go==="add" && $_POST["captchacode"] !== $_SESSION['captcha_spam'])
{
$error = "Wrong security code!";
}

if($go==="add" && $_POST["captchacode"] !== $_SESSION['captcha_spam'])
{
$error = "Wrong security code!";
}



?>
```

Best regards

Comment: this code has no relevance to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is a bit off your question. Anyways you need to use the functon mysql_num_rows to check how much record does your query returns.

Example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='dave'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "this user already exists in the database!";
}
```